# Error : "xlim" need finite values with interactivity of a while loop in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I created a while loop to solve a problem in a shiny script but when I want to make it interactive it doesn't work.

To simplify my problem I will describe it with a simplified data set.

My server.R looks like this, here the goal of the code is to replace all the values of the field or_gestion by 'AMEL' when the field RJV corresponds to 'J1'. Then the while loop is present to fill line by line the field or_gestion to increase the presence of the value 'REG' according to the value of the slider.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(sf)

function(input, output, session) {

uex <- reactive({
    uex$or_gestion[uex$RJV == "J1"] <- "AMEL"

    v <- 0
    while (v == input$renouvellement) {
      uex <- uex %>%
        mutate(count = ifelse(RJV=="J1", seq.int(1:nrow(uex)), NA)) %>% 
        group_by(RJV) %>%
        arrange(Priorite_renouv, area)
      uex$or_gestion[uex$or_gestion == "AMEL" & uex$count == v] <- "REG"
      v <- v+1
    }
    
  })

  output$GestionPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(uex()["or_gestion"], main="Orientation de gestion")
    
  })
}
```

I want to modify the or_gestion field with the while loop so that when we change the shiny slider to increase or decrease the 'REG' rate in the or_gestion field the map updates with the correct values.

my ui.R looks like this,

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
     navbarPage(
           tabPanel("Scenario de gestion (Libre)",
                  sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                      sliderInput("renouvellement", min = 1, max = 100, value = 1, step = 1, round = 0),
                         ),
                   
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("GestionPlot"),
          )
        ),
        ),
),
)
```

and my data (uex) looks like this,

| RJV | or_gestion | area | Priorite_renouv | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V | JEU | 5 |  |  |
| V | JEU | 8 |  |  |
| R | JEU | 9 |  |  |
| R | JEU | 15 |  |  |
| J1 | REG | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| J1 | AMEL | 20 | 1 | 1 |
| J1 | AMEL | 30 | 2 | 3 |
| J2 | AMEL | 4 |  |  |
| J2 | REG | 18 |  |  |
| J3 | JEU | 29 |  |  |

When I execute this code, I get the error :
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: 'xlim' need finites values

Thanks in advance for your advice and solutions !
NB : Sorry for my english it's not my mother tongue ;)

Comment: Initially, `v = 0` and `input$renouvellement` is 1, and therefore, you don't have `v == input$renouvellement`.  That means your while loop condition is not met.  Please check your logic.

Comment: This is not the problem, even if I set my starting values to 0, the shiny display still doesn't work :(

Comment: Your data wrangling is an issue.  Please ensure that it works outside of shiny.

Comment: Yes it works outside shiny i'm sure

Comment: Should you use `while (v <= input$renouvellement)`?

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work